# A question about the Repository pattern and MVVM

Tags: mvvm

I have a repository named MemberRepository which is used by the MemberListViewModel and the MemberEditViewModel. In the repository I have my GetMember(), CreateMember, SaveMember, Rollback(), and DeleteMember().

Throughout my app I have numerous lookup tables that populate comboboxes. Example Status, Trade Code, Agent, User etc. Where do I place the GetUsers, GetStatuses(), GetTradeCodes() methods? In the appropriate repositories in which they are used?

For example, the member view model needs a list of statuses, trade codes, classes, etc. So I would put the gets for these in the MemberRepository?

Bill

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so your `MemberListViewModel` is for a listing page and your `MemberEditViewModel` is an editing page.

What I would do, in my model, is expose the following classes:

- `ListMembersTask`
- `EditMemberTask`

You inject these with all the repositories each one would need, and they expose the properties and methods needed by some abstract thing that's performing each task.  For instance, `ListMembersTask` might have a method called `CreateMember()` that returns a new `EditMemberTask` initialized with an empty Member object.

Your `ViewModel` then gets injected with the appropriate Task (so `MemberListViewModel` gets injected with `ListMembersTask`, etc.).  Your `MemberListViewModel` would have a `RelayCommand` that called `CreateMember()` and took the returned `EditMemberTask`, injected it into a `MemberEditViewModel` and passed the new `MemberEditViewModel` to the presenter.

If you follow that approach, then the Repositories are only responsible for persistence.  A task wraps up the state of the business logic during a session, and a view-model just makes a task bindable.

*The next step I've been working on is to dispense with the Task-specific view-models, and I now hand a raw Task to the Presenter, and it inspects the object and builds a view-model hierarchy for the task out of elementary view-model elements (like `EditTextViewModel`, `ChooseOneViewModel`, `DockingLayoutViewModel`, etc.).*